# how to inject $cookie in custom service of angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am using angularjs and according to to its [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) i most use cookies with ngCookies. I add ngCookie with this structure :

1. add angular.js and angular-cookies.min.js to my index.html
2. inject ngCookie to to my app using this code :

   ```
   var app = angular.module('test',
   ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ngFileUpload','ngSanitize','ngCookies']);
   ```
3. and now i inject ng-cookie to my own service :

   ```
   app.service("transactionService",

     ["$cookie", "$http","sessionStorageService",
     function($cookie, $http, sessionStorageService){

           $cookies.put("unique_code",123456);
           console.log(sessionStorageService.getCurrentUser().sessionid);
           console.log($cookies.get("unique_code"));
           return;
       }
   ]);
   ```

but i am getting this error: 
    Error: [$injector:unpr]

where am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally my fault and it was really simple and foolish....
my angular js version was 1.3.0 but i get cookie from angular version 1.4.4 :(

Answer (score 4):

The name of the service is **[`$cookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)** and not `$cookie`.

Side note when developing use full version (not minified) of angular it provides much better error codes. The [`Error: $injector:unpr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) is documented and well known:

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a
>   required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined
>   and **spelled correctly**.

Comment: i correct my typo ... but still i am getting this error : http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProvider%20%3C-%20%24ookieReader%20%3C-%20%24cookies%20%3C-%20transactionService

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 Verify that the angular-cookies.min.js loaded properly if it did try to create a fiddle, plunker showcasing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have misspelled `$cookies`

```
     ["$cookie", "$http","sessionStorageService",
            ^
  function($cookie, $http, sessionStorageService){
```

`Error: $injector:unpr` => "Unknown Provider Error"

Check out [injector:unpr error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Also $cookies documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Answer (score 2):

if you use old Angular version then you should use $cookieStore instead of $cookie

```
app.service("transactionService",[
"$cookieStore","$http","sessionStorageService",

function($cookieStore, $http, sessionStorageService){

    $cookieStore.put("unique_code",123456);
    console.log(sessionStorageService.getCurrentUser().sessionid);
    console.log($cookieStore.get("unique_code"));
    return;
}]);
```